# Laravel ErrorException

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So i've made some changes. And I have no idea what happened, but this pops up on pretty much every view.

If anyone knows what's up, I would be very thankful.
Sometimes you make a change and just don't know what happened.

```
ErrorException in b3eeef2137d2dbfb09f05e2d167697b945108e1f.php line 12:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\system\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)
in b3eeef2137d2dbfb09f05e2d167697b945108e1f.php line 12
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\xampp\htdocs\reserveersysteem\storage\framework\views/b3eeef2137d2dbfb09f05e2d167697b945108e1f.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('C:\xampp\htdocs\reserveersysteem\resources\views/welcome.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in View.php line 149
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 45
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 201
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 1017
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in Router.php line 642
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 644
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 267
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

EDIT:
Below is the  code in my welcome.blade.php:

```
@extends("layout")
@section("content")
            <div class="content">
            <h1>Under Construction</h1>
                        <div class="logomainpage">

                        </div>
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    Reserveertool
                </div>

                <div class="links">
                  @if(Auth::user()->type == 1 || 2)
                    <a href="{{ url('/overview') }}">Overzicht zalen</a>
                  @endif
                    <a href="{{ url('/account') }}">Inloggen als bestaande klant</a>
                    <a href="{{ url('/reserveerzaal') }}">Zaal reserveren</a>
                    <a href="{{ url('/account') }}">Account</a>
                    <a href="{{ url('/contact') }}">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Show your code in welcome.blade.php

Comment: I've added them for you

Comment: The problem come from this line `Auth::user()->type`, do you have really a `type` attribute in your User  model ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it did work after adding that. But yes, I added the type attribute in my User model

Comment: Add `dd(Auth::user())` before the condition and check if you have `type`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not logged in during testing

Comment: More specifically, modify your comparison to be: `if(auth()->check() && in_array(auth()->user()->type, [1,2])`t

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that you added type attribute, add one more conditional step before this.

```
@extends("layout")
@section("content")
        <div class="content">
        <h1>Under Construction</h1>
            <div class="logomainpage">

            </div>
            <div class="title m-b-md">
                Reserveertool
            </div>
            @if (Auth::guest())
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
            @else
               <div class="links">
                  @if(Auth::user()->type == 1 || 2)
                     <a href="{{ url('/overview') }}">Overzicht zalen</a>
                  @endif
                     <a href="{{ url('/account') }}">Inloggen als bestaande klant</a>
                     <a href="{{ url('/reserveerzaal') }}">Zaal reserveren</a>
                     <a href="{{ url('/account') }}">Account</a>
                     <a href="{{ url('/contact') }}">Contact</a>
               </div>
           @endif
        </div>
@endsection
```